# CentOS 6.6 and CWP - DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, internal-dns, dns-zone

I installed the CentOS 6.6 and CWP on my second laptop, I think it is erroneous DNS information..

```
NS1: ns1.centos-webpanel.com | IP:185.4.149.83 [Change]
NS2: ns2.centos-webpanel.com | IP:185.4.149.90 [Change]
Server IP: 192.168.1.214 | 192.168.1.214
Shared IP: 94.123.179.83 [Change]
Hostname: es-264-cl.local [Change]
Yours IP: 192.168.1.163
```

**Server IP:** supposed to be public IP (I Think)
How can i resolve this error? Thank you
(I do not use a static IP)

Answer (score 0):

Please enter the command from your terminal

```
system-config-network-tui
```

This will allow you to configure the network settings manually but through a graphical interface. Please come back and comment if this works.

Comment: I write but system:" -bash: system-config-network-tui: command not found"

Comment: @Editor Try `yum install system-config-network-tui` tthen run the above command again.